# Cannot find AddMvc() in IServiceCollection in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a brand new asp.net core application.
I have added the mvc Nuget package yet I am getting the below error.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.1.3

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMvc' and no extension method 'AddMvc' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Either your package restore failed (see output console) or your assembly reference is missing in csproj or you missing the `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` declaration

Comment: I am getting now services.AddMvcCore but still cannot find AddMvc()

Comment: Remove .core from package name.

Comment: Was banging my head on this one neglecting to notice the `(extension)` indicator in the IntelliSense popup. The method is indeed an extension, and not defined by the interface. BTW, I was digging into the AddDbContext method which was also absent from the interface.

Answer (score 27):

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc -Version 1.1.3

--Update

Unload the project and Reload it again (restart)

Comment: This continues to pop-up in more recent version of dotnet core. If you run into it, visit the nuget package gallery to select the right version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/. Otherwise, this reply is spot-on!

Answer (score 14):

Try restarting visual studio 2017.

Sounds dumb I know, but it worked for me. I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, but Visual Studio still told me that "IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddMvc ...". I shutdown and restarted visual studio 2017 and the error message went away. Visual Studio 2017 is new and still seems to be a bit flaky, particularly with packages. Hopefully this will get fixed in a future update. Right Microsoft?

Comment: A restart was required from my copy of VS too. In VS 2017 the ***.csproj file was not viewable in the solution explorer window. I needed to open it from windows file explorer.

Comment: Plus one for the last sentence in the answer

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall any version of MVC from "Manage NuGet Package" window. Add this `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />` to "yourprojectname.csproj" file manually. It seems the problem is related to the version of the package.

Comment: Thanks, Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"` in `dependencies` section of `Startup.cs` in VS 2015 ASP.Net Core 1.0 project.

Answer (score 1):

I think , AddMvc changed to AddMvcCore()

Comment: No, that does something else.  AddMvcCore is more barebones.

Answer (score 0):

please add references

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
```

in your `projectname.csproj` file

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error with visual studio 2017 when trying an 'Empty Project' (aspnet core 1.1 templates) template when creating an 'Asp.Net Core Web Application'.

Installing the latest 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' on Nuget (version 2.2.0) failed with the message 'Package restore failed'. But installing a specific version (1.1.8) and reloading project (see Ahmed Al Jabri's answer above) fixed my error.